# How to Make this python program multiprocessing or multithreading

Tags: python

I have this python program, now i want to do multiprocessing or multithreading for this. Please help me achieve this.

```
import os, sys, codecs, random, time ,subprocess
years = ["2016","2017","2018","2019","2020"]
rf = open('URL.txt', 'r')
lines = rf.readlines()
rf.close()
list = []
for element in lines:
    list.append(element.strip())
files=["myfile1.txt","myfile2.txt"]
for url in list:
    for year in years":
        for file in files:
            os.system('python myfile.py -u' +url+ ' -y' +year+ '-f' +file)
            time.sleep(5)
```

I want to finish one url in one process or one thread.

Comment: what is the problem? You dont understand something here? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I am not fully understanding how to implement that in my current program..

Comment: Please dont use ```list``` as a variable name. That's extremely bad practice, and will cause more problems because list is a predefined data type in python and will cause conflict. Also, please attempt the problem from your side and post the attempt with error if you are unable to solve it. SO is not a free code service.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Its litterallty adding two lines to your code if you go by the very first example.

Comment: the first example is like this:
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))

but i don't have any function here

Answer (score 1):

You would add:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

You would separate your work into a function:

```
def myfunc(url, year, file):
    os.system('python myfile.py -u' +url+ ' -y' +year+ '-f' +file)
```

And then in place of the loop, you would make a list of argument tuples and send it to a pool using `starmap`:

```
pool = Pool(4)  # <== number of processes to run in parallel
args = [(url, year, file) for url in lst for year in years for file in files]
pool.starmap(myfunc, args)
```

(Here I changed `list` to `lst` -- please also change the lines in your code that use `list` to `lst` instead, because `list` is a builtin.)

---

**Update** - just noticed "I want to finish one url in one process or one thread."

You can do a more coarse-grained division by putting some of the looping into the payload function:

```
def myfunc(url):
    for year in years:
        for file in files:
            os.system('python myfile.py -u' +url+ ' -y' +year+ '-f' +file)
```

and then call it with just the URL - as it is only one argument, you don't need `starmap` any more, just `map` should work and the list of URLs

```
pool.map(myfunc, lst)
```

However, there is not much reason to divide it up in this way if the years and files can be done independently in parallel, because the coarse-grained division might mean that the job takes longer to complete (some processes are idle at the end while one is still working on a URL that is slow for some reason).  I would still suggest the first approach.